# Is the expression "how many" grammatically correct in the case below?

Tags: grammar

Please refer to the following dialogue. The words “how many” in Person B’s reply seem incorrect to me.  Are they correct? Shouldn’t these be rectified to “the number of robocalls” or something?

> - A: There’s no silver bullet, unfortunately. It’s pretty well impossible to stop getting robocalls completely.
> - B: But there are various ways to reduce how many you receive. A good way to start is to sign up with the National Do Not Call
>   Registry. You can register your landline or mobile phone with them for
>   no charge.

Comment: It’s fine; it means “how many robocalls.”

Comment: It's possibly below formal, but far more idiomatic than your formal suggestion in informal conversation.